# Get XML element that has '#' in the name

Tags: xml, powershell, soap

I have a program with a SOAP interface. The XML I get back has the '#' symbol in some element names. How do I get around that?

Here's a snippet of the XML file. I've listed snippets for "ID4" and "ID5". There are identical elements for "ID3" through "ID20". The snippets are surrounded by Envelope and Body tags:

```
<ns0:ArrayOfOption id="ID2" xsi:type="enc:Array" enc:arrayType="ns0:Option[18]">
    <item href="#ID4" />
    <item href="#ID5" />
</ns0:ArrayOfOption>   

<ns0:Option id="ID4" xsi:type="ns0:Option">
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">lps</name>
    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">en_es,es_en</value>
</ns0:Option>

<ns0:Option id="ID5" xsi:type="ns0:Option">
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">license.tr.tm</name>
    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</value>
</ns0:Option>
```

Here's a snippet of the script. :

```
[xml]$ex = get-content example.xml
for each ($i in $ex.Envelope.Body.Option){
    $i.name
    $i.value
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
type          #text
----          ----
xsd:string    lps
ID4
xsd:string    license.tr.tm
ID5
```

Using PowerGUI, which gives a graphical view of objects and their properties, I see that each element does have a property name "#text", with the hash symbol.
Two questions:
1) Why does the #text field have a '#' symbol? I'm in touch with the developers; can I ask them to change something in their source code (Java) to remove it?

2) Assuming I can't remove it, how do I get around it? If I want to assign the values and names to variables, I can't enter:

```
for each ($i in $ex.Envelope.Body.Option){
    $name = $i.name.#text
    $value = $i.value.#text
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The `#` is there because what follows is a "fragment identifier", i.e. a link relative to the current document (because the part before the `#` is empty).  The `#` is required since the attribute has the syntax of an `href`.

Comment: Also, your question is rather unclear.  What is `#text`?  You are iterating over the `ns0:Option` tags and the `#` characters appear only in the `href` attributes of items in the `ArrayOfOption` tag, which you are not examining at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the `#text` property put the property name in quotes e.g.:

```
$name = $i.name.'#text'
$value = $i.value.'#text'
```

Comment: I later found that each element has a property named "innerText" which holds the text between the flags. So I could have entered $i.name.innerText instead.